# Do destroyed checkpoints mend themselves if I restart a level by returning to the map?

Tags: shovel-knight

I've just discovered that the checkpoints can be destroyed to claim a gem, so I got a bit shovel happy and destroyed all of them. Now I'm finding the boss difficult, and unfortunately I keep spawning at the beginning instead of close to the boss.

If I return to the map and start the level over again will the checkpoints be intact once again? Or have I screwed myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that when you restart the game the checkpoints restart.

Looking online I can also see that things like death count and gems by going back to the map. I *think* this'll also mend checkpoints.